# Powershell, XML & Arrays

Tags: xml, arrays, loops, powershell

Currently, I'm building several arrays in Powershell, but to make the code more portable, I'd like to use XML files as a simpler (read more foolproof) way of managing how each array serves its purpose.

Array 1 is a master list of information - containing a rownumber, Name, retention, and Type. I would like for the XML to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ZipList>
    <Backup RowID="1">
        <RowNbr>1</RowNbr>
        <NameType>TargetBackup</NameType>
        <Retention>10</Retention>
        <FileType>Folder</FileType>
    </Backup>
    <Backup RowID="2">
        <RowNbr>2</RowNbr>
        <NameType>SourceBackup</NameType>
        <Retention>7</Retention>
        <FileType>Folder</FileType>
    </Backup>
    <Backup RowID="3">
        <RowNbr>3</RowNbr>
        <NameType>XMLBackup</NameType>
        <Retention>21</Retention>
        <FileType>File</FileType>
    </Backup>
</ZipList>
```

The array I currently build I use to loop thru it later on, and to build hash tables from as well.  So, I don't really want to re-engineer the rest of the powershell script.

However, since it's easier to make changes to an XML file (as opposed to changing the array inside the script), all I want to do is to duplicate this array in an XML file that would be a little more straightforward & self-documenting to make changes to, read this xml file in and then store it in the array I'm currently creating.

I can get the xml file read in, but I'm having trouble getting the xml data into an array.  For the above XML example, the array would look like this:

```
counter ++
arr1 += ,@(counter,1,"TargetBackup",10,"Folder")
counter ++
arr1 += ,@(counter,2,"SourceBackup",7,"Folder")
counter ++
arr1 += ,@(counter,3,"XMLBackup",21,"File")
```

and so on....

The issue I am having is that the xml data is in, but it's a string that I can't do anything with other than grab it all at once.  Any help, suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just export that array as clixml.  Then its portable, and when you want to use it in your script, just re-import it and you have your array back.

Comment: Initially, I did that.  The structure & naming conventions within the xml weren't very informative, and I don't think they could be customized, or at least not easily.

Comment: Looking at your data, I can't say that I see anything an XML format is providing you can't get by using a .csv file, and it would be much easier to deal with both inside and outside of the script.  IMHO.

Comment: I hadn't even considered that - you are 110% correct.  Thank you for suggesting the obvious solution I failed to even consider.

Comment: Side note: I usually use CLIXML instead of CSV even for a simple array of custom objects, mostly because types are roundtripped with CLIXML which is nice if you want to work with the data afterwards.

Comment: With V3, I'm finding convertto/from JSON is just as effective for most applications, and the resulting file is a lot easier read.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a follow-up, following is the code for what I did.  **Mjolinor's** suggestion of using a CSV file simplified (relatively speaking) the solution immensely (**Thank YOU**). I was definitely trying to make the solution too complex.

I created three CSV files that I used to drive the process.  First is the RotateBackups_Masterlist.txt file.  BackupName is the name of the backup as it's associated later on in the process.  VersionsRetained is the number to keep on hand.  BackupType is whether it's a file or folder backup.

```
RowNbr,BackupName,VersionsRetained,BackupType
1,TargetBackup,2,Folder
2,LstDefBackup,5,File
3,XMLBackup,3,File
4,SourceBackup,2,Folder
5,TXTBackup,8,File
```

Second file is RotateBackups_FolderList.txt.  BackupName corresponds to the same field in the above file, Foldername is the folder that's being backed up.

```
RowNbr,BackupName,FolderName
1,TargetBackup,c:\MyBooks\target
2,SourceBackup,c:\MyBooks\source
```

Third file is RotateBackups_FileExtensions.txt.  BackupName corresponds to the same field in the first file, FileExtension is the wildcarded name of the files to be backed up (it will accept patterns also), and FolderLoc is the folder where these items are to be found.

```
RowNbr,BackupName,FileExtension,FolderLoc
1,LstDefBackup,*.def,c:\MyBooks\target
2,LstDefBackup,*.lst,c:\MyBooks\target
3,XMLBackup,*.xml,c:\MyBooks\target
4,TXTBackup,*.txt,c:\MyBooks\rfiles
```

Please note that the same file extension can be backed up to multiple BackupNames.  Also, Multiple Folders can be assigned to the same BackupName and FileExtension.

What it does:

- It creates a folder with zip files in it that are named after the
  BackupName field (master file) plus a datetime stamp (all within the
  same batch) in the filename.
- The filenames all have the same BATCH date-time stamp so you will
  know that all the backups with ending with 20120401_091500.zip were
  all created out of the same run.
- It gives you the ability to version backups, and gives you a
  point-in-time to restore to.
- It gives you some flexibility in managing your backup space
  requirements. It gives you the ability to maintain a longer retention
  for critical backups or a shorter retention for less critical ones.
- Deleted items can be destructively deleted or recycled.
- Your backups do not age out based on the creation date.  The only
  thing that causes a backup to be marked for deletion is the creation
  of a newer one that puts the count over the number you want retained.

What it doesn't do:

- I don't have a lot of error handling in it, other than checking for
  empty arrays or the LASTEXITCODE immediately prior to deleting files.
- It's not meant for huge numbers of the same type of files to be
  backed up using the File Extension, as the backup is a one-at-a-time
  function call to create/update a zip file.

Lastly, the code that does the work (posted in entirety after comments).  I grabbed pieces of code for numerous parts of this from many sources, and thank the original poster/developer of each of them.  Use of this utility is at your own risk.  I welcome any improvements others might wish to add to this.

This is the function that creates the backup.

```
function create-7zip([String] $aDirectory, [String] $aZipfile){
    [string]$pathToZipExe = "C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe";
    [Array]$arguments = "a", "-tzip", "$aZipfile", "$aDirectory", "-r";
    & $pathToZipExe $arguments;
}
#  Call it by using:
#create-7zip "c:\temp\myFolder" "c:\temp\myFolder.zip"
```

Variables & Arrays are initialized here, Text files from above are imported here.  The variable $KillOrRecycle is set to Recycle, so anything deleted goes to recycle bin.  The Kill is a destructive, non-recoverable file deletion.

```
#************************************************************************************
#************************************************************************************
# Initialize variables
$zipFolder = "C:\ZipFiles"
$nameConv = "{0:yyyyMMdd_HHmmss}" -f (Get-Date) + ".zip"
$fileList = @{}
$FileCountArray = @()
$bkupTypeArr = @()
$myDocFolder = "c:\Documents and Settings\MyPC\My Documents\"

# Import text files for master, folder and file backup information
$bkupRotateMasterArr = Import-Csv $myDocFolder"RotateBackups_MasterList.txt"
$fldrBkupArray = Import-Csv $myDocFolder"RotateBackups_FolderList.txt"
$fileExtBkupArr = Import-Csv $myDocFolder"RotateBackups_FileExtensions.txt"

# Switch to delete Item or to send to recycle bin
#      delete is destructive and cannot recover file.  
#      Recycle setting removes file from folder, but sends to recycle bin
#      and can be restored if needed.
#      Must be either "Kill" or "Recycle"
$KillOrRecycle = "Recycle"
#************************************************************************************
#************************************************************************************
```

Load the contents of the imported CSV files into hashtables.
$bkup_Counts is a hashtable of the BackupName & Number of files to be retained.

$bkupTypeArr is an array of the BackupNames (used later on)

$fArray is a hashtable of the BackupName and the filename generated that's associated with it.
$nameConv is done at the top to give all files in this run the same date-time stamp.

```
# Load contents of master backup array
$bkup_Counts = @{}
$b = $null
foreach($b in $bkupRotateMasterArr)  
    {  
    $bkup_Counts[$b.BackupName] = $b.VersionsRetained
    }  


#set Backup Types from the array we just defined
$type = $null
foreach ($type in $bkup_Counts.Keys) {
    $bkupTypeArr += $type
    }

#create array of our filenames for this batch
$type = $null
$fArray = @{}
foreach ($type in $bkupRotateMasterArr) {
    $fArray[$type.BackupName] = ($type.BackupName + $nameConv)
        }
```

Next, if we have any data in the fileExtension array, run through it using the folder Location & file extension (recursively) to grab everything matching it from that path, associating it with the appropriate BackupName.  Add that to the $filelist hashtable that has the fullname property as the key, and the BackupName as the value it's associated with.

```
# if extension array not null, get list of files to back up
if ($fileExtBkupArr) {      
    #  Gather the list of files to be backed up
    $f = $null 
    foreach ($f in $fileExtBkupArr) {
            $arr = @()
            $arr = (Get-ChildItem $f.FolderLoc -Recurse -Include $f.FileExtension | Select-Object fullname)
            foreach ($a in $arr) {
                if ($a) {
                $fileList[$a] = $f.BackupName
                }   # if $a not null
            }   # end inner foreach
        }   # end outer foreach
}   # if FileExtension Backup Array not null
```

Then, if there's anything on the filelist hashtable, zip it to the appropriately named backup.

```
# if filelist count gt zero, then create zip file of them for appropriate backup
if ($fileList.Count -gt 0) {    # must have entries in hashtable
    $f = $null
    #Loop thru file list & associate file with the appropriate backup
    foreach ($f in $fileList.Keys) {
        $arcFile = $null
        if ($fileList.ContainsKey($f)) {
            if ($fArray.ContainsKey($fileList[$f])) {
                $arcFile = $fArray[$fileList[$f]]
                create-7zip $f.FullName $zipFolder\$arcFile
            } #if key in fArray
        }   # if key in Filelist
    }   # end foreach
}   # if hastable not empty
```

Next, if we have folders to back up, then use a similar process to back those folders up using a similar method.

```
# if folder backup not null then back up folders
if ($fldrBkupArray) {   # check if array not null (no entries)
    $f = $null
    #Backup Folders now
    foreach ($f in $fldrBkupArray) {
        $arcFldr = $null
        #if ($fArray.ContainsKey($f[1])) {
        if ($fArray.ContainsKey($f.BackupName)) {
            $arcFldr = $fArray[$f.BackupName]
            create-7zip $f.FolderName $zipFolder\$arcFldr
            }  #end if
        }  # end foreach
}  # end if $fldrBkupArray not null
```

Next item is to make sure that we had no failure prior to deleting anything.  We delete based on whether the archive bit is set, and send the deleted file to the recycle bin (default) or the bit bucket.

```
# if 7zip succeeded, we'll continue 
if ($LASTEXITCODE -gt 0)
    {Throw "7Zip failed" } 
ELSE {  # if Exitcode = 0 then continue with job
    # Remove any files with Archive bit = False 
    #    we marked it for deletion in previous run
    Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic
    $files=get-childitem -path $zipFolder
    # we'll delete all files that don't have the archive bit set 
    Foreach($file in $files) { 
        If((Get-ItemProperty -Path $file.fullname).attributes -band [io.fileattributes]::archive)
        { Write-output "$file is set to be retained" }
        ELSE {
            if ($KillOrRecycle = "Recycle") {
                Write-output "$file does not have the archive bit set. Deleting (Sent to recycle bin)."
                [Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.Filesystem]::DeleteFile($file.fullname,'OnlyErrorDialogs','SendToRecycleBin')
                $output = $_.ErrorDetails
                }
            ELSE {
                Write-output "$file does not have the archive bit set. Deleting."
                remove-item -recurse $file.fullname
                $output =$_.ErrorDetails 
                }
            } 
        }  #end Foreach
```

Next, export the BackupName & Counts to an xml file, Count the files (by BackupName type) in the archive folder, and then set the archive bit on ALL files so we can mark excess ones for deletion.

```
# Export BackupCounts to XML 
$bkup_counts | Export-Clixml bkup_counts.xml

# Get Number of ZIP files in folder
$btype = $null
foreach ($btype in $bkupTypeArr) {
    $FileCountArray += ,@(($btype),(dir $zipFolder\$btype"*.zip").count)
    }

# Import BkupCounts from XML
$bkup_Counts= Import-Clixml bkup_counts.xml

# set Attribute byte on ALL files in zipfolder so we know we'll get the right ones
attrib $zipFolder"\*" +a
```

Now, go back thru the bkup_Counts hashtable, getting the number of files matching the BackupName pattern, and subtracting the days of retention from the count of the number of files.  If the difference is greater than 0, then we have to delete that many entries from  that folder.

We do that by piping the folder using that same BackupName pattern, sorting it on the Creation Time property, then selecting the first N files, where N is the number greater than zero on the retention value above.

Then, for each object we selected, go back & set the Archive bit to FALSE to mark it for deletion on the next run.

```
    $row = $null
    # Get LST & DEF filenames in array & display count
    foreach ($row in $bkup_Counts.Keys) {
        Get-ChildItem -Path $zipFolder -Include $row"*" -Recurse #|
        (dir $zipFolder\$row"*".zip).count - $bkup_Counts[$row]
        $delfiles = 0
        $delfiles = (dir $zipFolder\$row"*".zip).count - $bkup_Counts[$row]
        if ($delfiles -gt 0) { #sort folder by createdtime 
            # if more than specified nbr of backups present, un-archive excess ones to delete next run.
            dir $zipFolder\$row"*" | sort-object -property {$_.CreationTime} |
            select-object -first $delfiles |
            foreach-object { attrib $_.FULLNAME -A} 
            } # end if delfiles gt 0
        }   # End foreach in bkup_counts

}  #  End Else Last ExitCode = 0
```

Here is the code in its entirety.

```
function create-7zip([String] $aDirectory, [String] $aZipfile){
    [string]$pathToZipExe = "C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe";
    [Array]$arguments = "a", "-tzip", "$aZipfile", "$aDirectory", "-r";
    & $pathToZipExe $arguments;
}
#  Call it by using:
#create-7zip "c:\temp\myFolder" "c:\temp\myFolder.zip"

#************************************************************************************
#************************************************************************************
# Initialize variables
$zipFolder = "C:\ZipFiles"
$nameConv = "{0:yyyyMMdd_HHmmss}" -f (Get-Date) + ".zip"
$fileList = @{}
$FileCountArray = @()
$bkupTypeArr = @()
$myDocFolder = "c:\Documents and Settings\MyPC\My Documents\"

# Import text files for master, folder and file backup information
$bkupRotateMasterArr = Import-Csv $myDocFolder"RotateBackups_MasterList.txt"
$fldrBkupArray = Import-Csv $myDocFolder"RotateBackups_FolderList.txt"
$fileExtBkupArr = Import-Csv $myDocFolder"RotateBackups_FileExtensions.txt"

# Switch to delete Item or to send to recycle bin
#      delete is destructive and cannot recover file.  
#      Recycle setting removes file from folder, but sends to recycle bin
#      and can be restored if needed.
#      Must be either "Kill" or "Recycle"
$KillOrRecycle = "Recycle"
#************************************************************************************
#************************************************************************************

# Load contents of master backup array
$bkup_Counts = @{}
$b = $null
foreach($b in $bkupRotateMasterArr)  
    {  
    $bkup_Counts[$b.BackupName] = $b.VersionsRetained
    }  


#set Backup Types from the array we just defined
$type = $null
foreach ($type in $bkup_Counts.Keys) {
    $bkupTypeArr += $type
    }

#create array of our filenames for this batch
$type = $null
$fArray = @{}
foreach ($type in $bkupRotateMasterArr) {
    $fArray[$type.BackupName] = ($type.BackupName + $nameConv)
        }

# if extension array not null, get list of files to back up
if ($fileExtBkupArr) {      
    #  Gather the list of files to be backed up
    $f = $null 
    foreach ($f in $fileExtBkupArr) {
            $arr = @()
            $arr = (Get-ChildItem $f.FolderLoc -Recurse -Include $f.FileExtension | Select-Object fullname)
            foreach ($a in $arr) {
                if ($a) {
                $fileList[$a] = $f.BackupName
                }   # if $a not null
            }   # end inner foreach
        }   # end outer foreach
}   # if FileExtension Backup Array not null


# if filelist count gt zero, then create zip file of them for appropriate backup
if ($fileList.Count -gt 0) {    # must have entries in hashtable
    $f = $null
    #Loop thru file list & associate file with the appropriate backup
    foreach ($f in $fileList.Keys) {
        $arcFile = $null
        if ($fileList.ContainsKey($f)) {
            if ($fArray.ContainsKey($fileList[$f])) {
                $arcFile = $fArray[$fileList[$f]]
                create-7zip $f.FullName $zipFolder\$arcFile
            } #if key in fArray
        }   # if key in Filelist
    }   # end foreach
}   # if hastable not empty

# if folder backup not null then back up folders
if ($fldrBkupArray) {   # check if array not null (no entries)
    $f = $null
    #Backup Folders now
    foreach ($f in $fldrBkupArray) {
        $arcFldr = $null
        #if ($fArray.ContainsKey($f[1])) {
        if ($fArray.ContainsKey($f.BackupName)) {
            $arcFldr = $fArray[$f.BackupName]
            create-7zip $f.FolderName $zipFolder\$arcFldr
            }  #end if
        }  # end foreach
}  # end if $fldrBkupArray not null


# if 7zip succeeded, we'll continue 
if ($LASTEXITCODE -gt 0)
    {Throw "7Zip failed" } 
ELSE {  # if Exitcode = 0 then continue with job
    # Remove any files with Archive bit = False 
    #    we marked it for deletion in previous run
    Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic
    $files=get-childitem -path $zipFolder
    # we'll delete all files that don't have the archive bit set 
    Foreach($file in $files) { 
        If((Get-ItemProperty -Path $file.fullname).attributes -band [io.fileattributes]::archive)
        { Write-output "$file is set to be retained" }
        ELSE {
            if ($KillOrRecycle = "Recycle") {
                Write-output "$file does not have the archive bit set. Deleting (Sent to recycle bin)."
                [Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.Filesystem]::DeleteFile($file.fullname,'OnlyErrorDialogs','SendToRecycleBin')
                $output = $_.ErrorDetails
                }
            ELSE {
                Write-output "$file does not have the archive bit set. Deleting."
                remove-item -recurse $file.fullname
                $output =$_.ErrorDetails 
                }
            } 
        }  #end Foreach

    # Export BackupCounts to XML 
    $bkup_counts | Export-Clixml bkup_counts.xml

    # Get Number of ZIP files in folder
    $btype = $null
    foreach ($btype in $bkupTypeArr) {
        $FileCountArray += ,@(($btype),(dir $zipFolder\$btype"*.zip").count)
        }

    # Import BkupCounts from XML
    $bkup_Counts= Import-Clixml bkup_counts.xml

    # set Attribute byte on ALL files in zipfolder so we know we'll get the right ones
    attrib $zipFolder"\*" +a 

    $row = $null
    # Get LST & DEF filenames in array & display count
    foreach ($row in $bkup_Counts.Keys) {
        Get-ChildItem -Path $zipFolder -Include $row"*" -Recurse #|
        (dir $zipFolder\$row"*".zip).count - $bkup_Counts[$row]
        $delfiles = 0
        $delfiles = (dir $zipFolder\$row"*".zip).count - $bkup_Counts[$row]
        if ($delfiles -gt 0) { #sort folder by createdtime 
            # if more than specified nbr of backups present, un-archive excess ones to delete next run.
            dir $zipFolder\$row"*" | sort-object -property {$_.CreationTime} |
            select-object -first $delfiles |
            foreach-object { attrib $_.FULLNAME -A} 
            } # end if delfiles gt 0
        }   # End foreach in bkup_counts

}  #  End Else Last ExitCode = 0
```